# Вызов функции из swf

Tags: windows, flash, c++, swf

Есть swf файл, нужно вызвать в нем функцию и получить результат. Желательно сделать это из c++. Переписать код на с++ нельзя. Как сделать без лишнего геморроя?

- Из с++ можно открыть флеш через Flash::IShockwaveFlash и вызвать функцию, но она должна быть обьявлена так: flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback("foo1", this.TestFunction1); В файле, который требуется открыть такого нет и не будет.
- Есть подозрение, что можно написать простой swf с приведенной выше функцией и сделать в нем загрузку нужного файла. Не подскажете, куда копать? Я не работал с action script. Буду благодарен за пример, который загружает файл и вызывает из него функцию.
- Возможно есть код для выполнения кода swf файла по типу виртуальной машины? Выполнить инструкции и дело с концом.

Answer (score 1):

Коментарии я оставлять почему-то не могу, но раз ответов нет, то скажу вот что...
Вы можете создать swf и загрузить в него Ваш swf, но вызывать его методы сможете,
если они имеют модификатор доступа public. Но обычно все свойства и методы инкапсулируют объявляя, как приват. 
Других вариантов нет...
Если не секрет, то у Вас какая-то очень редкая swf? Или Вы что-то нашли и дальше заморачиваться не хотите?

Comment: У меня нехорошая swf, использующаяся для защиты программы. Программа вызывает ее функцию и получает код. Мне нужно сделать так же. У вас нет кода для загрузки swf и вызова функции?

Comment: Я сейчас as3 не занимаюсь и даже ide пока не установил. Но в гугле очень много примеров. И Вы самое главное помните - если эта swf сделана не для Вас, то и её методов Вам не вызвать. А если они и есть, но swf все равно предназначена не Вам, то 99% что метод ожидает ключ в параметрах...

Comment: Примеров много, но вот заставить их работать оказалось не так легко. В общем задача решена. Создал свою swf подгрузил чужую, вызвал метод. Все работает как часы.

Comment: Уж не от игровых автоматов софт?